# Overwrite Proxy Settings on Database Server for technical user

Tags: powershell, ssis, proxy, powerbi

I have to refresh power Bi dataset in an automated way. For it, I am using Microsoft API running it through Powershell script which is calling Microsoft API. This Powershell script is embedded inside a SSIS package and run through a SQL Server Agent job(technical user calling the job). Since its a database server, we have to add proxy settings for the technical user (through which SQL Agent job is running) to connect to the internet and call the Microsoft Power Bi API's to refresh the dataset. Now, when the technical user is somehow logged-in to the machine, the powershell script is able to refresh the datasets since it detects the proxy settings but when it is not logged in, it is unable to execute the APIs. Is there a way we can overwrite the proxy settings on the server.

Comment: First check the log files to see what logins where used.  SSIS there is a log file with the app under the start button.  SQL Server has a log file you can see using SSMS in the explorer under Management.  The credential should be passed automatically from client through proxy through SSIS to SQL Server.  You need to determine if SQL Server Credentials are being used, Windows Credentials are being used, Or OAUTH2 (token) credentials are being used.  You need to use Credentials where password is encrypted (not a username and password).

Comment: If you are using Windows Credentials, than all machines need to be in the same domain where they share a common password server.